# Algorithms for event filtering and trigger

Tags: algorithm, events, stream, complex-event-processing

Here is the problems I have on hand -

I have a series of "lower level" event-streams (concurrent database record creations) like - "Matt has got a 4* rating in Commitment (dimension)"... and have pre-defined "higher level" event criteria like - "If someone gets 4* rating in Commitment AND >=3* in Mentorship", trigger the event. This will happen over any(N) number of users (Mat and his fellow mates) throughout the system.

What's the right way to approach it. First thing that comes to mind is of CEP (Complex Event Processing). Guys, any suggestions/pointers will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is not strictly an algorithm for your problem, but towards the design of your program. There is a related idea called [Event-Based Components](http://ebclang.codeplex.com/). This helps you to design event driven systems, which are different from traditional request-response design. Maybe you will find this useful in your application design.